# shower water cold

Tags: shower

I have a tub/shower combo in the master bath.  The water is HOT when turned on and comes out of the faucet. When I pull the shower tab and turn the shower on, the water is cold.  I've let the tub water run a long time and the temperature is always HOT. When I turn the shower off and the water is coming out of the faucet again, its again HOT. All of the facuets in the house are fine. The other shower is fine. This is the only fixture that has this problem. I've changed the shower head and no difference.  The water pressure is fine just the temperature issue.

Comment: What is "the shower tab"?  Is that on the tub spout or a part of the water valve?

Comment: The part on the spout that turns off the faucet and the shower head on.

Comment: Do you have a tankless water heater or a tank? If you unscrew the shower head and have unrestricted flow out the shower line, does the water stay hot?

Comment: If you keep the cold valve closed and have only the hot valve on, do you get a significant flow of hot water out the shower?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds similar to my "shower only" stall.

A plumber told me there is a set screw under the cover that adjusts the hot/cold mix.  He said that many people turn this down when selling a house so that the inspector won't find scolding hot water on inspection.  Then new owners can turn it back up for a hot shower.

It did help my situation.

~ Just a thought.

Comment: I was thinking of a anti scald valve but have seen the adjustable ones I thought both tub and shower were the same setting? Good to note.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested the solution to this problem was me flushing my tankless heater via this post:

[How I fixed my cold water sandwich problem.](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/183858/rinnai-water-heater-flush-procedure)